# For loop should iterate for no of lines of command output in shell scripting

Tags: shell, for-loop

I had run a command ls. output of this is in few lines,say

1. my country
2. india

I have to write for loop as for line in (ls);

```
do
    rm -rf line
done
```

problem i am facing is for loop is taking my, country as separate inputs. but i want it to take each line as single input, say "my country"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ls | while read -r line ;

```
do
  rm -rf "$line"
done
```

It worked.